# Why is checking for a json mimetype not working in my Request?

Tags: laravel, validation, request, mime-types

I have a Laravel API and I make a custom Request to validate the values. I'm testing my routes via Postman and I added a JSON file to my settings field. But when I try to validate the mimetype in my custom request an error gets thrown. When I remove `|mimetypes:application/json` the route returns a response successfully. Why is this happening?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:32|unique:game_templates',
        'path' => 'required|string|url|unique:game_templates', 
        'settings' => 'required|file|mimetypes:application/json',
        'orientation' => Rule::in(GameTemplate::$orientations),
    ];
}
```

[image]

The JSON content

```
{
    "name":"test"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are actually uploading a file with the `application/json` mimetype? A .json extension doesn't automatically mean it's `application/json`. Also note the following from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-mimetypes):

> To determine the MIME type of the uploaded file, the file's contents will be read and the framework will attempt to guess the MIME type, which may be different from the client provided MIME type.

Comment: I think so, I added the JSON content to my question

Comment: In that case try this instead `required|file|mimetypes:application/json,text/plain`

Comment: It's a success, but why?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23143) contains some background info on it.